# RAILS Query - How to use the 'where' method - rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I am new to rails - any help would be much appreciated.

- I have a list of created job `adverts`
- `Advert` is a model
- In the schema `Advert` is a table with the columns `title`, `content` & `deadline`
- I would like to only display `adverts whose deadline are '= or >' than Date.current` (active adverts)

Unfortunately I am unsure how to do it.
I tried the below in the console:

```
active_adverts = Advert.where(:deadline > Date.current)
```

Could one kindly advise me on how to display adverts that have a
deadline greater than the current date?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the following syntax:

```
active_adverts = Advert.where('deadline >= ?', Date.current)
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: You should also check out scopes. If you create a scope in your Advert model like: `scope :active, -> { where("deadline >= ?", Date.current) }` then you can re-use whenever you are doing an activerecord query on Adverts e.g. `Advert.active` or if a user has_many adverts `@user.adverts.active`